# CSS selector for element before another element/remove list-style-type of nested uls

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have nested uls like this:

```html
    <ul>
      <li>1...</li>
      <li>2...</li>
      <li id="li_3">
      <ul>
          <li id="li_3_1">3.1...</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>4...</li>
    </ul>
```

li_3 displays a bullet but I don't want it to since its children li already do (there are 2 bullets side to side near li_3_1).

So I wanted to select all the li having a ul as a direct child, something like this:

```
ul < li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

But of course the selector < doesn't exist. What solutions do I have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `list-style` in nested `ul`, this selector may be helpful.

```
ul > ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Nah I do want the li in the nested list to have bullets, if I do this it removes all the bullets in the nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the `li` directly using it's ID in CSS using this code:

```
#li_3 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Or if there are multiple you could just add a class to every `li` you want the bullet removed from and use the same code.

working:

```css
#li_3 {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>1...</li>
      <li>2...</li>
      <li id="li_3">
      <ul>
          <li id="li_3_1">3.1...</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>4...</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I would like a generic solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
li:has(ul) {list-style-type: none;}
```